# Need to run python script in an environment where python is not present

Tags: python, unix, executable

I need to run python in an environment where there wont be python. Is it possible to execute python as an executable in Unix Environments, like HP-UX, IBM-AIX, Solaris, Linux etc etc....

The targeted OS is AIX now.... since it does not have python support and the installation is difficult......

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [Freeze](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze).

Comment: Other than freeze, the common factor on all these systems is the C compiler, so a translation to C would do it, too.

Comment: I used cv_freeze and it works well on Linux to Linux....... But I need to find out if I can do from Linux to AIX

Answer (score 1):

I have used http://www.pyinstaller.org/  to create an executable in ubuntu. look at their [manual](http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/d3398dd79b68901ae1edd761f3fe0f4ff19cfb1a/project/doc/Manual.html?format=raw#linux), it also have the cool feature of outputting just one file with `--onefile`. My first choice was `freeze` but the executable failed to run when I used some external modules - I could not solve it and I found pyinstaller to be perfect for me.